# Need advice on how to index and optimize a specific MySQL database

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my MySQL DB so I can query it as quickly as possible.

It goes like this:

My DB consists of 1 table that has (for now) about 18 million rows - and growing rapidly.
This table has the following columns - idx, time, tag_id, x, y, z.
No column has any null values.

'idx' is an INT(11) index column, AI and PK. right now it's in ascending order.

'time' is a date-time column. it's also ascending. 50% of the 'time' values in the table are distinct (and the rest of the values will appear probably twice or 3 times at most).

'tag_id' is an INT(11) column. it's not ordered in any way, and there are between 30-100 different possible tag_id values that spread over the whole DB. It's also a foreign key with another table.

INSERT -
A new row is being inserted to the table every 2-3 seconds. 'idx' is calculated by the server (AI). since the 'time' column represents the time the row was inserted, every new 'time' that's inserted will be either higher or equal to the previous row. all the other column values don't have any order.

SELECT -
here is an example of a typical query:
"select x, y, z, time from table where date(time) between '2014-08-01' and '2014-10-01' and tag_id = 123456"

so, 'time' and 'tag_id' are the only columns that appear in the where part, and both of them will ALWAYS appear in the where part of every query. 'x', 'y' and 'z' and 'time' will always appear in the select part. 'tag_id' might also appear in the select part sometimes.

the queries will usually seek higher (more recent) times, rather then the older times. meaning - later rows in the table will be searched more.

INDEXES-
right now, 'idx', being the PK, is the clustered ASC index. 'time' has also a non-clustered ASC index.

That's it. considering all this data, a typical query will return results for me in around 30 seconds. I'm trying to lower this time. any advice??

I'm thinking about changing one or both of the indexes from ASC to DESC (since the higher values are more popular in the search). if I change 'idx' to DESC it will physically reverse the whole table. if I change 'time' to DESC it will reverse the 'time' index tree. but since this is an 18 million row table, changes like this might take a long time for the server so I want to be sure it's a good idea. the question is, if I reverse the order and a new row is inserted, will the server know to put it in the beginning of the table quickly? or will it search the table every time for the place? and will putting a new row in the beginning of the table mean that some kind of data shifting will need to be done to the whole table every time?

Or maybe I just need a different indexing technique??
Any ideas you have are very welcome.. thanks!!

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/gilad905/bd30b5c3e5dd8c0165fc47c173ac0a54] (Some debugging tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select x, y, z, time from table 
where date(time) between '2014-08-01' and '2014-10-01' and tag_id = 123456
```

Putting a column inside a function call like `date(time)` spoils any chance of using an index for that column. You must use only a bare column for comparison, if you want to use an index.

So if you want to compare it to dates, you should store a `DATE` column. If you have a `DATETIME` column, you may have to use a search term like this:

```
WHERE `time` >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00 AND `time` < '2014-10-02 00:00:00' ...
```

Also, you should use multi-column indexes where you can. Put columns used in equality conditions first, then one column used in range conditions. For more on this rule, see my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

You may also benefit from adding columns that are not used for searching, so that the query can retrieve the columns from the index entry alone. Put these columns following the columns used for searching or sorting. This is called an index-only query.

So for this query, your index should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `this_table` ADD INDEX (tag_id, `time`, x, y, z);
```

Regarding ASC versus DESC, the syntax supports the option for different direction indexes, but in the  two most popular storage engines used in MySQL, InnoDB and MyISAM, there is no difference. Either direction of sorting can use either type of index more or less equally well.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll check out your advices

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill! I did what you said about adding the 00:00:00 to the time query and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, on StackOverflow it is customary to given an upvote for helpful answers or check the 'accepted answer' button for the answer that was most helpful.